# Kerberos 5 won't install on Debian 8.2 or 8.3

Tags: debian, kerberos, debian-jessie

I've been running some VMs in VirtualBox and cannot get Kerberos5 installed.

I keep receiving the error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 krb5-kdc : Depends: krb5-config but it is not installable
            Depends: krb5-user but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have this problem on fresh installs of Debian 8.2 and 8.3, any thoughts?

EDIT

**Sources:**

```
deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8.3.0 _Jessie_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20160123-19:03]/ jessie contrib main
deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8.3.0 _Jessie_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20160123-19:03]/ jessie contrib main
deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib
```

there are **no files** in `sources.list.d` directory

**Policies:**

```
$ apt-cache policy krb5-kdc
krb5-kdc:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.12.1+dfsg-19+deb8u2
  Version table:
     1.12.1+dfsg-19+deb8u2 0
        500 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages

$ apt-cache policy krb5-config
krb5-config:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:

$ apt-cache policy krb5-user
krb5-user:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.12.1+dfsg-19+deb8u2
  Version table:
     1.12.1+dfsg-19+deb8u2 0
        500 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages
```

- I tried installing on the clean install, after installing the necessary items (sudo etc)
- I've done a `sudo apt-get update`, tried Kerberos
- I've gone through Synaptic to install all the dependencies which were listed as:

  ```
   Depends: libgssrpc4 but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: libkadm5clnt-mit9 but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: libkadm5srv-mit9 but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: libkdb5-7 but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: libverto1 but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: krb5-config  but it is not installable
   Depends: krb5-user but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: libverto-libev1 but it is not going to be installed or
      libverto-libevent1  but it is not installable
  ```

`krb5-config` and `krb5-user` files would not install at any stage.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Please show your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and the contents of any files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. Also: Please show the output of `apt-cache policy {krb5-kdc|krb5-config|krb5-user}`, that is, `apt-cache policy <pkg>` for each of the listed packages. Besides: Did you do anything yourself to try to solve this problem?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, have edited the original post with the requested info

Answer (score 1):

According to the content you've provided of your `sources.list` file, you're missing entries, that's why the install fails.

- Add this:

  ```
  deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main
  deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main

  deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main
  deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main
  ```
- run `apt-get update` and try to do the install again.